# Get the index of an element excluding an element with a specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a list which may or may not have a non-selectable list-item added to it dynamically. It looks like this (with the non-selectable list-item included):

```
<ul class="list js-list ">
  <li class="listLabel">
    <span>Make Selection:</span>
  </li>
  <li class="js-sppmg__li">
    <span class="listItem js-listItem" data-filter-id="All">All</span>
  </li>
  <li class="js-sppmg__li">
    <span class="listItem js-listItem" data-filter-id="One">One</span>
  </li>
  <li class="js-sppmg__li">
    <span class="listItem js-listItem" data-filter-id="Two">Two</span>
  </li>
  <li class="js-sppmg__li">
    <span class="listItem js-listItem" data-filter-id="Three">Three</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I click on the third list item which is `data-filter-id="Two"`, I want the index:

```
parentIndex = $(this).parent().index();
```

to exclude the first, non-inclusive element which is `listLabel`. Is it possible to not include it in the index count? I've tried using `.not()` and class selectors etc but it returns either the same value as always (**3** instead of **2**) or **-1**.

Comment: `.closest('.listItem')` instead of `.parent()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select all `li` except `.listLabel` using `:not()` selector

```js
$(".listItem").click(function(){
  var index = $(this).closest("ul").find("li:not(.listLabel)").index($(this).parent());
  console.log(index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list js-list ">
  <li class="listLabel">
    <span>Make Selection:</span>
  </li>
  <li class="js-sppmg__li">
    <span class="listItem js-listItem" data-filter-id="All">All</span>
  </li>
  <li class="js-sppmg__li">
    <span class="listItem js-listItem" data-filter-id="One">One</span>
  </li>
  <li class="js-sppmg__li">
    <span class="listItem js-listItem" data-filter-id="Two">Two</span>
  </li>
  <li class="js-sppmg__li">
    <span class="listItem js-listItem" data-filter-id="Three">Three</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works - thank you! I had forgotten to add the .parent() to the final .index().

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this `parentIndex = $(".js-sppmg__li").index($(this).parent());`

This will give you the index of a parent with the class `.js-sppmg__li`

**Demo**

```js
$(".js-listItem").click(function(){
  parentIndex = $(".js-sppmg__li").index($(this).parent());
  console.log(parentIndex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list js-list ">
  <li class="listLabel">
    <span>Make Selection:</span>
  </li>
  <li class="js-sppmg__li">
    <span class="listItem js-listItem" data-filter-id="All">All</span>
  </li>
  <li class="js-sppmg__li">
    <span class="listItem js-listItem" data-filter-id="One">One</span>
  </li>
  <li class="js-sppmg__li">
    <span class="listItem js-listItem" data-filter-id="Two">Two</span>
  </li>
  <li class="js-sppmg__li">
    <span class="listItem js-listItem" data-filter-id="Three">Three</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should apply a click event on `li.js-sppmg__li > span` instead `.list li`

```
$('li.js-sppmg__li > span').on('click', function(){
    var parentIndex = $(this).parent().index(); 
     parentIndex = parentIndex-1;
     console.log(parentIndex);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you require by using `index()` and providing it with a selector to find the group of elements to retrieve the index within. Try this:

```js
$('.js-listItem').click(function() {
  var index = $(this).index('.js-list .js-listItem');
  console.log(index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list js-list ">
  <li class="listLabel">
    <span>Make Selection:</span>
  </li>
  <li class="js-sppmg__li">
    <span class="listItem js-listItem" data-filter-id="All">All</span>
  </li>
  <li class="js-sppmg__li">
    <span class="listItem js-listItem" data-filter-id="One">One</span>
  </li>
  <li class="js-sppmg__li">
    <span class="listItem js-listItem" data-filter-id="Two">Two</span>
  </li>
  <li class="js-sppmg__li">
    <span class="listItem js-listItem" data-filter-id="Three">Three</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check it..

```js
$('.js-list .js-sppmg__li').on('click',function(){
var nthelement=$(this).index()
if(nthelement==3)
alert(nthelement);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list js-list ">
 <li class="listLabel">
  <span>Make Selection:</span>
 </li>
 <li class="js-sppmg__li">
   <span class="listItem js-listItem" data-filter-id="All">All</span>
 </li>
 <li class="js-sppmg__li">
   <span class="listItem js-listItem" data-filter-id="One">One</span>
 </li>
 <li class="js-sppmg__li">
   <span class="listItem js-listItem" data-filter-id="Two">Two</span>
 </li>
 <li class="js-sppmg__li">
   <span class="listItem js-listItem" data-filter-id="Three">Three</span>
 </li>
```